# lvalue-to-rvalue conversion of an array in ISO C

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2008, language-lawyer, lvalue-to-rvalue

C++ ANSI ISO IEC 14882 2003 Annex C.1 (page 668):

Change: The result of a conditional expression, an assignment expression, or a comma expression may bean lvalue
Rationale: C + + is an object-oriented language, placing relatively more emphasis on lvalues. For example, functions may return lvalues.
Effect on original feature: Change to semantics of well-defined feature. Some C expressions that implicitly rely on lvalue-to-rvalue conversions will yield different results. For example,

```
char arr[100];
sizeof(0, arr)
```

yields 100 in C + + and `sizeof(char*)` in C.
...

I was reading this just today and I remembered that a couple of months a go a friend of mine proposed a problem wchich was to write a function that would return 0 if it were compiled with C++ and 1 if it were compiled with C. I solved it taking advantage of the fact that in C a struct was in the outer scope. So, considering this new information, I decided that this would be another solution to the above problem, which I tried on Microsoft Visual Studio 2008, but regardless of whether it is compiled as C or C++ code `sizeof(0, arr)` always yields 4. So 2 questions:

1.What is ISO C? Is it the current C standard? Is it the only one (I hear C is rapidly evolving)
2. Is this a microsoft C++ bug?

TIA

***Edit: Sorry got mixed up with the output and edited it:***

Comment: With MSVC 2010, `sizeof(0, arr)` appears to evaluate to `4` (when compiled as C++).  With g++, it evaluates to `100`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or just microsoft's C is not ISO C but some other standard C (if there exists any).

Microsoft Visual C still supports C89 [only] whereas other compilers like gcc/clang etc support [C99](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99) too which is the current Standard.

C99 [Section `6.5.17/2`] says

> The  left  operand  of  a  comma  operator  is  evaluated  as  a  void  expression;  there  is  a  sequence point after its evaluation.  Then the right operand is evaluated; the result has its type and value.<sup>95</sup>

Thus the result of `sizeof (0,arr)` would be `sizeof(char*)`[due to the implicit `lvalue` to `rvalue` conversion /automatic decay to pointer type] not `100*sizeof(char)`

`sizeof(arr)` would have given `100*sizeof(char)` from `6.5.3.4/3`

<sub>95)  A comma operator does not yield an lvalue.</sub>

---

> decided that this would be another solution to the above problem, which I tried on Microsoft Visual Studio 2008, but regardless of whether it is compiled as C or C++ code sizeof(0, arr) always yields 4.

C++03 [`5.18/1`] Comma Operator

> The type and
>   value of the result are the type and value of the right operand; the result is an lvalue if its right operand is.

So  `sizeof(0, arr) = sizeof (arr)` and which would be equal to `100* sizeof(char)` and not = `sizeof(char*)`.

So MSVC++ is giving incorrect result (in case of C++ code).

Comment: @Prasoon: does the 95) refer to C or C++?

Comment: @Armen : `C99` [..] Edited my post for clarity.

Comment: Sometimes I wonder why I am still using MSVC. But then they have an awesome IDE...

Comment: @Armen : Yeah right! But the compiler is broken and has no C99 support yet. Bad! Bad! Bad! `:(`

Comment: @ Prasoon: Their compiler is undoubtedly horrible (from a pedantic point of view), but their IDE is the best. A natural question arises... isn't it possible to integrate Comeau or g++ compiler with MSVS IDE? I smell a new thread :)

Comment: I have never tried that but I don't think that's **im** possible. Any MS guy out there? Haha!

Comment: @Prasoon which arises one more question. Where ARE the MS guys? I mean there are zillions of threads about MSVC non-compliance in a thousand of forums but I haven't seen any answer like - Hi I am from Microsoft, we are sorry we will fix it. The best you can hope for is "Hi, we know about the issue but it is not a priority. MAYBE we will address it in future releases" :(:(:(

Answer (score 4):

ISO C is *the* C standard. The current one is C99 but C1x is right around the corner. If by rapid, you mean a new standard every decade or so, then yes, it is rapidly evolving :-)

Section 6.5.3.4/3 of ISO C99 states:

> When applied to an operand that has type char, unsigned char, or signed char, (or a qualified version thereof) the result is 1.
>
> **When applied to an operand that has array type, the result is the total number of bytes in the array.**

Answer (score 0):

For arrays, the `sizeof` returns the total size. Be careful about arrays passed as pointers.

C99 standard:

> When applied to an operand that has array
>   type, the result is the total number of bytes in the array